# Roblox Studio - Function unintentionally running multiple times at once

Tags: lua, roblox

There is an unintentional thing in my game where if I run a function again, the functions overlap each other, but I don't want that.

When I run the function again, the function overlaps the other previously ran function.

The script:

```
local eids = script.Parent.EnemyIDSelected
local userinput = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent
local enemycount = frame.Enemies.NumberOfEnemies
local enemyorder = frame.Enemies.Frame:WaitForChild("EnemyOrder")

userinput.InputBegan:Connect(function(input,gameProcessedEvent)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.A or input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Left then
        eids.Value = eids.Value - 1
    elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.D or input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Right then
        eids.Value = eids.Value + 1
    end
end)

eids.Changed:Connect(function()
    if eids.Value > enemycount.Value then
        eids.Value = 1
    elseif eids.Value < 1 then
        eids.Value = enemycount.Value
    end
end)

eids.Changed:Connect(function()
    local number = 0

    local function findenemies()
        local enemycount = frame.Enemies.NumberOfEnemies.Value
        local enemies = {}
        local ordernumber = 1
        for i, v in pairs(enemyorder:GetChildren()) do
            if string.sub(v.Name, 1, 5) == "Order" then
                enemies[ordernumber] = v.Value
                if ordernumber == enemycount then
                    return enemies
                end
                ordernumber = ordernumber + 1
            end
        end
    end
    local enemies = findenemies()
    --
    
    while wait() do
        for i, v in pairs(enemies) do
            if i == eids.Value then
                print(number)
                script.Parent.ImageLabel.TextLabel.Text = enemies[i].EnemyValue.Value
                enemies[i].ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(80, 80, 80)

                for i2, v2 in pairs(enemies) do
                    if v2 ~= enemies[i] then
                        v2.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(80, 80, 80)
                    end
                end

                wait(0.15)
                enemies[i].ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
                wait(0.15)
                number = number + 1
            end

        end
    end
    
end)
```

When I run the function again, the function overlaps the other previously ran function.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the function from running simultaneously you need to store whether the function is currently running, and for any new calls, check if it is already running.
For example:

```lua
local currentlyRunning = false

function test()
    if currentlyRunning then return end
    currentlyRunning = true
    
    task.wait(5)
    
    -- Very important if you have any return statements, put this line infront of them.
    -- Otherwise, the execution of the function may stop and 
    currentlyRunning = false
end
```

If instead you are trying to cancel stop the execution of the previous function when the event is fired again you should move the part of your script that handles the visualisation outside of the callback and just reference variables set by the callback. This lets you avoid the issues and hassles of dealing with coroutines.

For example:

```lua
local enemies = 0

event:Connect(function()
    enemies +=1
end)

RunService:Hearbeat:Connect(function()
    print(enemies)
end)
```

Also, in your script, you are listening to the same event multiple times, this is bad practice since it may cause issues with the ordering of the functions being ran. You should instead put them into the same :Connect statment.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, can you please explain more about how these work?